# Writable nested serializer in django-rest-framework?

Tags: python, django, rest

My design is as following about Django ModelSerializer.
There are model A and model B. Model B has a foreign key field of Model A. For some reasons, I can not use the primary key directly to serialize Model B. As my thought, what I need is to serialize two other fields(unique together in Model A).

And I see the SlugRelatedField must be used for one slug field. 
I searched there is a NaturalKeyField can support NaturalKeyField. But it looks like it is superseeded by django-rest-framework. But I checked the django-rest-framework, there is no such field at all.
Can anyone help?? What should I do?

The code is as following.
Model A

```
class AssetModel(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Org, related_name='models')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    model_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default = 3,choices = MODEL_TYPE )
    directory = models.CharField(max_length = 128)
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('org', 'name',)
```

Model B

```
class Dataitem(models.Model):
    mod = models.ForeignKey(AssetModel, related_name='dataitems')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    data_type = models.SmallIntegerField(default =0,choices = DATAITEM_DATATYPE)
    ...
```

Serializer of model A

```
class AssetModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    org =  serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Org.objects.all(), slug_field='name')
    class Meta:
        model = AssetModel
        fields = ('org', 'name', 'model_type',..
```

Serializer of model B

```
class DataitemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dataitem
        fields = ('mod', 'name','data_type'...)
```

The primary key of Model A is just a id Django auto added. When serialize the model B, I need to get the org and name of model A. Both read and write are needed.

Comment: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-serializers

Comment: I think the better _question_ would be to **post your models and explain what you want to achieve**, instead of asking about a solution you thought of

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Nested Serializer

You can do something like this, define a serializer for `Dataitem` that can reuse a serializer of the `AssetModel` model

```
class AssetModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AssetModel

    # Fields org and name of AssetModel will be inlcuded by default

class DataitemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dataitem

    mod = AssetModelSerializer()
        # This is the Dataitem.mod field
        # which is a FK to AssetModel,
        # Now it'll be serilized using the AssetModelSerializer
        # and include the org and name fields of AssetModelSerializer
```

I prefer this approach because of the control I get.
If you serialize using the above you get a structure like this:

```
data_item = {'name': ..., 'mod': {'org': ..., 'name': ...}}
                          ^
                          |___ AssetModel fields
```

### Alternatively you can also use `depth = n`

You can also use `depth = 1` in `Dataitem`

```
class DataitemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Dataitem
            depth = 1 # Will include fields from related models
                      # e.g. the mod FK to AssetModel
```

### Writable Nested Serializer

> Because the behavior of nested creates and updates can be ambiguous,
>   and may require complex dependencies between related models, REST
>   framework 3 requires you to always write these methods explicitly.

We have to implement `create/update` to make this writable as per [DRF's documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations)

```
class DataitemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Dataitem

    # Nested serializer
    mod = AssetModelSerializer()

    # Custom create()
    def create(self, validated_data):
        # First we create 'mod' data for the AssetModel
        mod_data = validated_data.pop('mod')
        asset_model = AssetModel.objects.create(**mod_data)

        # Now we create the Dataitem and set the Dataitem.mod FK
        dataitem = Dataitem.objects.create(mod=asset_model, **validated_data)

        # Return a Dataitem instance
        return dataitem
```

Comment: There are other fields in AssetModel, which I do not want to serialize them. To use nested serializer, do I have to define a new serializer only includes org and name fields?

Comment: Yes simply use `fields = (...)` like you did

Comment: thanks a lot. But it looks like the write on the mod fields would fail.

Comment: No problem! I'd try get a recent version of DRF and read this about writable nested serializers http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: @ThomasLiu You're welcome. I've added an example so you can relate to your models. Be aware that this example is for 1 nested model, but if AssetModel itself needs a FK key you will have to unpack more data from `validated_data` and create the object, link the FK etc. I suggest you practice this with a simple 1 nested model first. I Hope this puts you on the right track. Please upvote/accept the answer if it helped you! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

There seems to be a library that does this
[drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested)

it handles the creation and serialisation of these types

- OneToOne (direct/reverse)
- ForeignKey (direct/reverse)
- ManyToMany (direct/reverse excluding m2m relations with through model)
- GenericRelation (this is always only reverse)

Comment: Just got to try it out, `is_valid` acts funny for now but in general it does work!! And is really easy to try. This answer should be bumped up