# Django Rest Framework: Allow child models to be created either within a parent or seperately

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

Say I have a set of nested serialisers like:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = ['id', 'name']


class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ChildSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'children']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        children = validated_data.pop('children')
        parent = super().create(validated_data)
        for child in children: 
            child['parent'] = parent
        self.fields['children'].create(children)
        return parent
```

If I send the payload to the `ParentViewSet`:

```
payload = {
    'name': 'parent',
    'children': [
        {
            'name': 'child',
        }
    ],
}
```

It creates both models fine, but if I send the following payload to the `ChildViewSet`:

```
payload = {
    'name': 'child',
    'parent': parent.pk,
}
```

It will fail because it `parent` isn't included in the `Child` serializers `field` attribute. If you include the attribute, the reverse is true. The second payload works, but the first one fails because you aren't including the `parent` field (since you're creating the two models at the same time).

Is there a way around this behaviour? I'd like to have create methods for both `Parent` and `Child`, but I can't seem to configure my serialisers to do this.

**Edit:**

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class Child(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Child, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children')
```

Comment: The best approach to achieve this is to define another set of serializers.

Comment: You can do this with SerializerMethodField... but to give a good answer, I would need to see your models.py file. Can you add the specification for Child and Parent model please?

Comment: Could you give me an example? I haven't managed to find anything online.

Comment: @Celebrian I've added the models.

Comment: Ah sorry... I was typing up an answer and then saw that SerializerMethodField does not work for Create. In other words, you can only use it for GET method, not for POST or PUT. You'll have to try something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using another serializer, as JPG sugested in comments. One approach could be the following:

```
class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'parent']

class ParentChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Child
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class ParentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    children = ParentChildSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Parent
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'children']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        children = validated_data.pop('children')
        parent = super().create(validated_data)
        for child in children: 
            child['parent'] = parent
        self.fields['children'].create(children)
        return parent
```

Here in your ChildViewSet, you can use ChildSerializer, and in your ParentSerializer, you can use ParentChildSerializer.