# Override django serializer or models create method

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to add data to my database. To this purpuse, I have a vue function :

```
@api_view(['POST'])
  def update_add_bges(request):
    serializer = BGESSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

this one call a serializer to add new data in the database :

```
class BGESSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
  laboratoire = LaboratoiresSerializer()

  class Meta:
    model = BGES
    fields = '__all__'

  def create(self, validated_data):
    laboratoire_data = validated_data.pop('laboratoire')
    laboratoire_oj = Laboratoire.objects.create(**laboratoire_data)
    validated_data["laboratoire"] = laboratoire_obj["pk"]
    bges = BGES.objects.create(**validated_data)
    return bges
```

The problem is that my Laboratoire classe is nested as well, and should add instances from an other class :

```
class LaboratoiresSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

  tutelles = TutellesSerializer(many=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Laboratoire
    fields = '__all__'

  def create(self, validated_data):
    tutelles_data = validated_data.pop('tutelles')
    laboratoire = Laboratoire.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for tutelle_data in tutelles_data:
      t = Tutelle.objects.get(nom=tutelle_data["nom"])
      laboratoire.tutelles.add(t)
    return laboratoire
```

This is not working, because not called as it's the create of the serializer and not the create of the Models.
How should I do ? When I add a Laboratoire, I have Tutelle to create ... Should I implement the create in the Models ? As I am new to django, I have hard time to understand the subtility of functions calls.

Comment: This link might help you with the creation of nested objects via DRF serializer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784979/writable-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to create a writable nested serializer when you have a depth of 2, i.e. two nested serializers. Fortunately, you've already written the code in `LaboratoireSerializer` that creates the `Laboratoire` and `Tutelle` objects based on `validated_data`, so you can do this:

```
class BGESSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  

    class Meta:
        model = Laboratoire
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 2

    def create(self, validated_data):
        laboratoire_data = validated_data.pop('laboratoire')
        laboratoire_obj = LaboratoireSerializer.create(self, laboratoire_data)  # note we don't instantiate the serializer! 
        validated_data["laboratoire"] = laboratoire_obj  # note we pass the object not pk
        bges = BGES.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return bges
```

The trick here is to call the method `create` on the class, passing `self` into it. It works because the `create` method doesn't actually care about `self` and doesn't use it. I wouldn't work if `self` was used in the `create` method of `LaboratoireSerializer` and expected to be a `LaboratoireSerializer`. It's hacky, I know, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for this, there is still something I don't get, why does django remove pk keys from nested object. In validated_data, I no longer have my pk value from the LaboratoiresSerializer.create function, so I'm not able to get tutelles ids. Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe add `depth = 2`? But validated data should contain the actual instances, not the pks.