# Django Rest - Posted data creating new rows in Foreign key referenced tables

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to post data to my orders model. It has several foreign keys. When I tried to post data, it is trying to create objects in the referenced models also.
My models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import Profile

class Nursery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Plants(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/plants')
    price = models.IntegerField()
    nursery = models.ForeignKey(Nursery,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Plants,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    order_id = models.UUIDField(auto_created=True)
    is_purchased = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    nursery = models.ForeignKey(Nursery,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

So, I tried posting data into Order model, and it gave error `Plant name already exists` meaning that it is trying to create a row in Plants and Nursery models also.
My serializers.py:

```
from .models import Plants,Order,Nursery
from rest_framework import serializers

class NurserySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Nursery
        fields = "__all__"

class PlantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nursery = NurserySerializer()
    # nursery = NurserySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Plants
        fields = ['name', 'price','image','nursery']


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', read_only=True)
    product = PlantSerializer()
    nursery = serializers.CharField(source='nursery.name', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['user_name', 'product','date_ordered','order_id','is_purchased','cost','quantity','nursery']
```

Views.py:

```
class PostOrder(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
       print(request.data)
       serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
       if serializer.is_valid():
           serializer.save()
           return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
       return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784979/writable-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework) might be helpful. I'm using [drf-writable-nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) in my project and it's really helpful.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz in the thread you have provided, it creates a row in the referenced table also. I don't want to do that. That is the posted data should create only in the `Order` table. But it will create rows in `Nursery` and `Plants` table also

Comment: Then I think you need to use `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()` instead of `PlantSerializer()`. But this way, you will get only the IDs of the relationships when you retrieve the order. Therefore you would need to split your serializer into two, 1 for read and 1 for write.

Comment: Only getting the IDs of the relationships is fine as when we insert data into Order table, we insert ids of the relationship. So, in serializers,py by changing `serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField()`  from `PlantSerializer()`, can we post data without inserting new rows in the referenced tables

Comment: you want creating in where

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG Yes for your last comment, you just need to provide the primary key of the relation in the post data Order, and no new instance of the relation will be created.

Comment: @danish_wani Thank you, it's working when I provided the primary key of relation and no new instance is being created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this,

sorry, i don't understand you want creating new rows in where

```
from .models import Plants,Order,Nursery
from rest_framework import serializers

class NurserySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Nursery
        fields = "__all__"

class PlantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nursery = NurserySerializer(read_only=True)
    # nursery = NurserySerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Plants
        fields = ['name', 'price','image','nursery']


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=True,slug_field='username')
    product = PlantSerializer(read_only=True)
    nursery = NurserySerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['user', 'product','date_ordered','order_id','is_purchased','cost','quantity','nursery']
```

Comment: It is working now, thanks. Also, this solution would also work.

Comment: what, i don't know, wkwkwk, I just fixed your code