# Django Rest multilevel nested POST data in serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have nested JSON data like below:

```
{
"resourceType": "Patient",
"identifier": [{
    "use": "usual",
    "type": {
        "coding": [{
            "code": "MR",
            "display": "Medical Record Number"
        }],
        "text": "Medical Record Number"
    },
    "system": "http://example.com",
    "value": "1032702",
    "assigner": {
        "reference": "Organization/198723168",
        "display": "Reference Organization",
        "data": {
            "resourceType": "Organization",
            "implicitRules": "",
            "language": "",
            "contained": "",
            "extension": "",
            "alias": "",
            "contact": "",
            "modifierExtension": "",
            "active": true,
            "name": "Clinic",
            "address": [{
                "line": [
                    "3300 Washtenaw Avenue, Suite 227"
                ],
                "city": "Amherst",
                "state": "MA",
                "postalCode": "01002",
                "country": "USA"
            }]
        }
    }
}]
}
```

In serializers create method, I want to get the `data` which is nested to `identifier->assigner` and store that in organization serializer which different than this to which I am POSTing these data. For top level data I can do like `validated_data.pop('identifier')`. Is there a similar way for nested one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writable nested serializer in django-rest-framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784979/writable-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework)

Comment: No @SamiTahri, I am doing like this for now:
`identifier = validated_data.pop('identifier')
assigner = identifier['assigner']`.
I was looking to avoid 2 line of code and make that happen in sigle line.