# Django Rest Framework: Saving Nested Serializer Workaround

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**Question**:

I need to save several objects using nested serializers using DRF.

[Documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/writable-nested-serializers/) about saving nested serializers seems to be incomplete.

Workarounds suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784979/writable-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers) answers do not seem to follow Python's encapsulation principle. As if we treat serializer as an object that encapsulates CRUD of a certain model, it is counter-intuitive to perform an object creation in serializer that "belongs" to another model.

**In-detail explanation of a question**:

Lets say we have two models:

```py
class A:
    content = models.CharField()
class B:
    content = models.CharField()
    relation = models.ForeignKey('A')
```

And two corresponding serializers:

```
class BSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = '__all__'
class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    b_field = BSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'
```

Sample of JSON that has to be saved:

```
{
    "content": "sample",
    "b_field": [
        {
            "content": "sample"
        }, 
        {
            "content": "sample"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using the workarounds suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784979/writable-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers), I have to override `create` method of `ASerializer` to smth like this:

```
class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    b_field = BSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        b_field_data = validated_data.pop('b_field', None)
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        if b_field_data:
            for obj in b_field_data:
                B.objects.create(
                    content=obj.content,
                    relation=instance
                )
        return instance
```

However, as I've already pointed out above, it is kind of counter-intuitive to process `class B` instance creation in serializer that is responsible for `class A`.
What is even less obvious, is that in the above `ASerializer.create` method, the nested `BSerializer`, when accessed via `self.fields['b_field']` appears to be not-instantiated. Thus, I eventually need to instantiate and validate it **once again** in order to access `BSerializer.create`:

```
class ASerializer(ModelSerializer):
    b_field = BSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        b_field_data = validated_data.pop('b_field', None)
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        if b_field_data:
            extra_instance = self.fields['b_field'](data=b_field_data)
            if extra_instance.is_valid():
                self.fields['b_field'].save(relation_id=instance.id)
                # I'm skipping further logic of BSerializer.save to simplify explanation
        return instance
```

I would appreciate any suggested workarounds of this issue.

Thank you.

---

**References**:

[1]: [Writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/writable-nested-serializers/)

[2]: [Writable nested serializer in django-rest-framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784979/writable-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework)

[3]: [Django Rest Framework writable nested serializers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28078092/django-rest-framework-writable-nested-serializers)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to manage such inside the `serializer` then you can move one level up, to the `view` and use `ModelSerializer's` to validate and create data related to each `Model`. Here is  an example using `ModelViewSet`:

serializers.py

```py
class BSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ["content", "relation"]
        extra_kwargs = {"relation": {"write_only": True}}


class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    b_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ["id", "content", "b_field"]

    def get_b_field(self, obj):
        related = obj.b_set.all()
        return BSerializer(related, many=True).data
```

views.py

```py
class AModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.A.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ASerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        b_field = request.data.pop("b_field")

        # Validate and create 'A' model instance.
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        a_instance = serializer.save()

        # Add relation field and serialize 'B' models
        for obj in b_field:
            obj["relation"] = a_instance.id
            b_serializer = BSerializer(data=obj)
            if b_serializer.is_valid():
                b_serializer.save()
            else:
                a_instance.delete()
                return Response(
                    {"error": "b_field data must be valid."},
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
                )

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

### Alternatively

It is also possible to pass data via [extra context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context), although in this case you would also have to override the serializer `.create` method:

serializer.py

```
class AlternativeBSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = B
        fields = ["content"]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        a_instance = self.context["a_model_instance"]
        return self.Meta.model.objects.create(**validated_data, relation=a_instance)


class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
```

views.py

```py
class AlternativeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ...

        # Use 'A' instance inside the serializer
        b_serializer = AlternativeBSerializer(
            data=b_field, many=True, context={"a_model_instance": a_instance}
        )
        if b_serializer.is_valid():
            b_serializer.save()
        else:
            a_instance.delete()
            return Response(
                {"error": "b_field data must be valid."},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```