# Setting instance on child ModelSerializer for update

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is our data model:

```py
class Parent:
    child = models.OneToOneField(Child)
    name = models.CharField()


class Child:
    name = models.CharField()
```

We get a incoming request that contains full data for an instance of Parent and its Child as nested data, and we want to deserialize it (and eventually create or update the instances). Below is some example payload:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dad",
    "child": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Kiddo"
    }
}
```

Here are the matching Serializers:

```py
class ParentSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ("child", "name")

    child = ChildSerializer()

class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ("name",)
```

In our view code:

```py
try:
    parent = Parent.objects.get(id=request.data["id"])
except Parent.DoesNotExist:
    parent = None

serializer = ParentSerializer(data=request.data, instance=parent)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

In the case that a Parent and Child exist in the database and a request comes in, a ValidationError is raised with `code=unique`, because it detects that the instance of Child mentioned in the payload already exists in the database. This is not something we want.

In my understanding, serializers validate the uniqueness of the primary key ("create" mode) unless they are bound to an instance ("update" mode).

In the case of the `ParentSerializer`, we can explicitly set the `instance=parent` argument. But how do we do this for the `ChildSerializer`?

---

EDIT: this hacky workaround fixes it:

```py
try:
    parent = Parent.objects.get(id=request.data["id"])
except Parent.DoesNotExist:
    parent = None

serializer = ParentSerializer(data=request.data, instance=parent)

if parent:
    try:
        serializer.fields.fields["child"].instance = parent.child
    except Child.DoesNotExist:
        pass

serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
```

Comment: Nested writes are not supported, and you are actually trying to do an upsert on child objects which is even more challenging.  You will have to manually manage those relationships.  I would recommend deserializing the entire object graph you are uploading and then, in a single transaction, creating the objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writable nested serializer in django-rest-framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784979/writable-nested-serializer-in-django-rest-framework)

Comment: @Andrew although the code here doesn't show it, I have overridden the create and update methods for both serializers. I just expected DRF to do the logic of assigning instances to serializers for me, as I did in the workaround, because that is how each serializer decides whether to call `create` or `update` when `save` is called.

Comment: This is purely a deserialization issue, not a write / upsert issue. The issue happens before I call save(). Will edit my question to remove unnecessary details.